# Is my OnBoard graphics chip really capable of rendering VR or is it a flaw in the steam checking tool?

Tags: steam, vive, steam-vr

My mainboard is a Asus Z87-A Mainboard.
It just left warranty after detecting it can't supply enough power while powering up, so it just turns off in booting process as soon a graphicscard is pluged.

So actually I'm just playing with the integrated chip.

I consider to buy a Vive VR.
But when I was seeing it is requiring GPU's along the series `970` I just throw off the idea of beeing able to use it without replacing the broken mainboard. But when I entered the automated hardware compatibility check, it actually detected and named the internal chip of my board correctly (haven't to hand right now).

And it displayed it to be fully capable for vive VR at highest performance with the mark at the most rightest of the green bar.

Is this just a bug in their automated test? or is the chip of my mainboard really that strong and I'll be able to use it?

(If it matters, I'm using an intel i7 CPU)

Comment: Most mid range to high range cards will require a direct connection from the power supply.  Did you forget to plug that in?  And this doesn't really belong here either.  Probably power user or the hardware recommendation beta.

Comment: @Nelson: It worked for 2 years and then stopped working, I exchanged multiple parts for testing and it is clearly some capacitor or a part that alike thats broken. Thanks for your attempt to help, but this is not the topic anyway :)

Comment: @Nelson: Well actually I thought it would be ontopic here, since I'm asking mainly about steam software and a possible bug in it. but If thats wrong I won't protest against migrating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt an integrated GPU is enough to have an high framerate (at least 90FPS) at 1080p or bigger to enjoy VR..

I think you will have to replace some hardware

Comment: So your answers conclusion is its a flaw in their hardware test?

Comment: totally ! onboard GPUs are not powerful enough to render VR games (at this time, I'm sure Intel and AMD will improve their chips in the future)